# ODE theory question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to get a hint for this question:

"let $p(x)$ , $q(x)$, be continuous functions at $\mathbb{R}$, and the ODE $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0 $ . Prove that if $y_1(x) \neq 0$, $y_2(x)$ solve the ODE, so $h(x) =\frac{y_2(x)}{y_1(x)}$ is a strictly monotone function or a constant function."

I didn't write my attempts because I barely know how to begin with this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's differentiate $h$ :
$$
h' = \frac{y_2'y_1-y_2y_1'}{y_1^2} = -\frac{W[y_1,y_2]}{y_1^2} \verb+  +\mathrm{where}\verb+  + W[y_1,y_2] = \left|\begin{array}{cc} y_1&y_2 \\ y_1'&y_2' \end{array}\right| = y_1y_2'-y_1'y_2
$$
is the Wronskian. If $y_1,y_2$ are linearly dependent, it is equal to zero (because it is a determinant) and then $h$ is constant. When they are linearly independent, [the Wronskian is known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian#Application_to_linear_differential_equations) to be $W[y_1,y_2](x) = Ce^{P(x)}$, where $P(x)$ is an antiderivative of $p(x)$ and $C$ an arbitrary constant, hence $h' = -Ce^P/y_1^2$, which has a constant sign, that is why $h$ is monotone in consequence.

Comment: Do we actually need the minus sign near the derivative? Besides that, worked like a charm. Much appreciated:)

Comment: Not really, since it can be absorbed by the constant $C$ in the end, or you could consider $W[y_2,y_1]$ instead. You're welcome ;)